# request.getContext from another servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, request

I'm using tomcat and created servlet 1, also created another servlet 2. I need to call servlets 1 context parameters but although I tried `(request.getSession().getAttribute("defaultuser")` for getting servlet 1 session, using it in `getContexts` context as `(request.getContext().getAttribute("defaultcont")` gives error `the method getContext is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest`. Is there any other way or a certain code to get servlet 2 context parameters?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html: here's the documentation of HttpServletRequest. We don't know what you mean by context parameters of a servlet, since that doesn't exist. Post the code, and explain what you're trying to achieve, instead of poorly describing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused with context and config.

Servlet config object is one per servlet.

Context object is one per web-app.(application-scope).
that means your context parameters can be accessed in all of your servlets by using...

getServletContext().getInitParameter("context-param-name") ;

You said...I need to call **servlets 1 context parameters** ...?
thats a wrong statement...

Tip: See that your context-param element is not inside any other servlet element in your web.xml file

Hope this helps.

Comment: yesssssssssssss..  I know that only 1 context is allowed, but I was looking for how to access it.. thanks it works now..